# What is the applications.json made by redmine on Cpanel/WHM

Tags: json, cpanel, redmine

I installed the Redmine on the Cpanel/WHM server.
After that, I found the file /var/cpanel/userdata/USERD/applications.json.
It might be able to access the /home/USER/redmine from the URL http://example.com/redmine.

I want to make sure that what system uses the file and led to access the Redmine.